# Include android TTS as a library

Tags: android, android-install-apk, google-text-to-speech

Is it possible to include android TTS engine as a lib in my app? Or to download it without user intervention?

Rigth now, if you want to use it, in some devices you have to download it first. Which means that the user is sent to the Google Play page of the TTS app and has to manually download it.

I am looking for an alternative to this, so the user has no intervention in the process.

Comment: You can redirect to Google play for TTS app without user intervention..

Comment: Yes but then the user has to "press the button" to download it. I dont want it.

When you install something in a pc, some of its requirements are installed without you even notice, thats what I'm looking for